# Question answer count incorrect for one question in the android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, answers, android-app

This question says it has 0 answers, but there is one at the time of writing. I tried closing it and going back in but still it had the old count. If it's a cache issue is expect it to be consistent with itself.

This question: [Retrieving a list of questions closed as duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193392/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-all-stackoverflows-questions-that-are-duplicate)

Comment: No repo for me, but that's not saying too much.

Comment: Expecting consistency from inconsistent caches is a bit optimistic.

Comment: With all the bugs being reported, maybe android is the problem, not the app. FWIW I do quite fine in the mobile layout in Chrome or Safari, aside from a few missing features (like flagging comments).

Comment: @AaronBertrand was just going to say the same thing.

Comment: Just went back into that question. It loaded with no answers. I scrolled to the right and pulled to refresh and they then appeared.

Comment: Sounds like caching

Comment: Same thing for this one http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193404/should-i-ask-a-question-on-stackexchange-sites-if-and-only-if-i-can-expect-a-sin both answers were posted "1 min ago", so definitely sounds like caching.

Comment: @Mat: I meant I'd expect the android app to be consistent. i.e. don't contradict itself on the same screen!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next build will do a better job of keeping the answer count updated at the top after a refresh.  This will be in version v0.1.17

Let me know if you continue to see an issue.